# How to execute batch queries?

Tags: yql

If I have an array containing a number of urls:

```
['http://www.abc.com', ..., 'http://www.xyz.com']
```

for each url, I would like to fetch the html with the following query:

```
select * from html where url=[url from array]
```

Question: do I need to make request to yql for every single url in the array or is there a way to send a single request to yql with all the urls and receive a bulk response ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the following query:

```
select * from html where url in ('http://www.yahoo.com','http://www.google.com')
```

Alternatively, you could also use yql.query.multi YQL table which allows you to combine different YQL queries.eg:

```
select * from yql.query.multi where queries="select * from html where url='http://www.google.com';select * from html where url='http://www.javarants.com/rss'"
```